# Postgress Crosstab - return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tentando usar o crosstab no postgres mas...

```
CREATE TABLE tb_testect
(
  datahora timestamp without time zone,
  teste integer
);
```

*** Correção**

```
INSERT INTO tb_testect VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 08:30:00',1);
INSERT INTO tb_testect VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 09:45:00',2);
INSERT INTO tb_testect VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2016-01-02 15:30:00',2);
INSERT INTO tb_testect VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2016-01-02 18:00:00',1);
INSERT INTO tb_testect VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2016-01-02 20:30:00',2);
INSERT INTO tb_testect VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2016-01-02 21:00:00',1);
INSERT INTO tb_testect VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 11:30:00',1);
INSERT INTO tb_testect VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 12:30:00',2);
INSERT INTO tb_testect VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 16:30:00',2);
INSERT INTO tb_testect VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2016-01-02 17:30:00',2);

select * from tb_testect;
```

*** Correção**

```
datahora            | teste
--------------------+-------
2016-01-01 08:30:00 |  1
2016-01-01 09:45:00 |  2
2016-01-02 15:30:00 |  2
2016-01-02 18:00:00 |  1
2016-01-02 20:30:00 |  2
2016-01-02 21:00:00 |  1
2016-01-01 11:30:00 |  1
2016-01-01 12:30:00 |  2
2016-01-01 16:30:00 |  2
2016-01-02 17:30:00 |  2
```

Quando executo o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab('
    select teste, date(datahora), "time"(datahora)
    from tb_testect ORDER  BY 1,2') 
    AS ct ("teste" int, "data" timestamp , "hora1"  timestamp, "hora2" timestamp);
```

Gostaria que o retorno fosse:

*** Correção**

```
 teste |    data    |  hora1   |  hora2   |  hora3
-------+------------+----------+----------+---------
     1 | 2016-01-01 | 08:30:00 | 11:30:00 |
     1 | 2016-01-02 | 18:45:00 | 21:00:00 |
     2 | 2016-01-01 | 18:00:00 | 21:00:00 | 16:30:00
     2 | 2016-01-02 | 13:30:00 | 20:30:00 | 17:30:00
```

Mas o que está retornando é o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR:  return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
```

*** Correção** : Preciso mostrar hora1, hora2, hora... dos dias 2016-01-01, 2016-01-02,...

Alguma idéia do que posso estar fazendo de errado?
Obrigado.

Comment: Os dados do retorno desejado não estão na tabela. Tem alguma lógica oculta ou simplesmente você não atualizou a tabela ao atualizar o retorno?

Comment: Não tinha atualizado o post. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A segunda coluna da consulta fornecida ao [`crosstab`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) existe só para ordenação e não é retornada. No seu caso basta extrair a data de uma das colunas `timestamp` retornadas:

```
select teste, hora1::date as data, hora1::time, hora2::time
from
    crosstab ('
        select teste, date(datahora), datahora
        from tb_testect
        order  by 1,2
    ') as ct (teste int, hora1 timestamp, hora2 timestamp )
;
 teste |    data    |  hora1   |  hora2   
-------+------------+----------+----------
     1 | 2016-01-01 | 08:30:00 | 18:00:00
     2 | 2016-01-01 | 09:45:00 | 15:30:00
```

### Novo

Com a revisão da pergunta parece que o que você quer não é crosstab mas sim agrupamento:

```
select
    teste, datahora::date as data,
    min(datahora)::time as hora1, max(datahora)::time as hora2
from tb_testect
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
;
 teste |    data    |  hora1   |  hora2   
-------+------------+----------+----------
     1 | 2016-01-01 | 08:30:00 | 11:30:00
     1 | 2016-01-02 | 18:00:00 | 21:00:00
     2 | 2016-01-01 | 09:45:00 | 12:30:00
     2 | 2016-01-02 | 15:30:00 | 20:30:00
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @clodoaldo-neto. Está **quase** certo aqui para mim. Fiz uma correção no post. Preciso mostrar hora1, hora2, hora... dos dias 2016-01-01, 2016-01-02,... 
Tem como fazer isso? Obrigado

Comment: Atualizei o post novamente. Obrigado

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez pois está me ajudando muito. E peço desculpa, pois acho que não fiz corretamente o **exemplo** . Alterei agora e inclui dois registros (**teste** 2).